# line break is not counted in character count

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a following code that counts the number of characters in a file using **awk**. 
but it doesn't count the line breaks as it is counted in `$ wc file`

file:abc

12345 
12345 
12345 
12345 
12345 
 
**awk command:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)c++}END{print "total chars:"c}' abc
```

This gives me o/p as

```
Total char:25
```

but if i run same abc file as `wc abc` it gives me o/p as `30 characters`

Any suggestions whether i can use two file separators at a time???

Comment: @sudo_O i'm waiting for you pro...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `Any suggestions whether i can use two file separators at a time?`: What is a `file separator`? How is needing 2 of them related to you problem of counting characters?

Answer (score 5):

This is based on @Scrutinizer's solution to show one way to handle files that might not end in a newline (using GNU awk for `RT`) to address @konsolebox's concern:

```
gawk '{t+=length+(RT?1:0)} END{print t}' file
```

or, more efficiently, as @konsolebox pointed out:

```
gawk '{t+=length} END{print t+NR-(RT?0:1)}' file
```

To accommodate empty files:

```
gawk '{t+=length}END{print t+NR-(!RT&&NR?1:0)}'
```

Comment: +1 When you mentioned END, I analyzed and thought about RT and how it could be compared in END. But it seems like you placed it on the body instead.

Comment: A more efficient solution I think would be `gawk '{t+=length}END{print t+NR-(RT?0:1)}' file`

Comment: yeah, it could be tested in the END too. I try not to do too much in END since not all awks retain the last $0 (or other variables?) in the END section, but in this case the solution is gawk-specific anyway so it could be done in the END. I'll update it with an alternative. Ah, I see you posted the alternative in your followup comment, I'll use that.

Comment: I think my suggestion needs correction. It would print `-1` on files with no record at all. It should be like `gawk '{t+=length}END{print NR?t+NR-(RT?0:1):0}'` or `gawk '{t+=length}END{print t+NR-(!RT&&NR?1:0)}'`.

Comment: OK, I updated it, thx. Finding it hard to accept we're putting all this effort into a solution that `wc -c` already handles :-)!

Answer (score 3):

Like I noted in this thread: [Multiple Field separator in awk script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805385/multiple-field-separator-in-awk-script/18807578#18807578) `awk` can only give a correct result for proper text files, where limits like maximum line lengths are observed and the last lines ends with a newline, whereas wc does not have this limitation..

```
awk '{t+=length} END{print "Total chars: " NR+t}' file
```

`wc` does not care and will just count the characters..

=== edit ===
This might work:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{
    m++
    next
  }
  {
    t+=length
  }
  m==FNR-1{
    RS="§"
  }
  END{
    print "Total chars: " FNR+t-1
  }
' file file
```

or in one line:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ m++; next } { t+=length } m==FNR-1{ RS="§" } END{ print "Total chars: " FNR+t-1 } ' file file
```

The file is read twice to determine the number of lines and then at the second pass the record separator gets changed..

Comment: This is not consistent with lines not ending in newline.

Comment: @konsolebox: That is what I said (which can be the case for the last line with the default RS )...

Comment: @konsolebox: I added another possibility with standard awk (not using gawk's `RT`)

Comment: I tried your update. I'm sorry but it doesn't seem to work well on counting newlines. It returns `-1` too with files not having any record. Also is there no possible issue with buffers if you already do `RS="\x1c"`?

Comment: @konsolebox, you are right, it would not work right with zero or one line. RS would not be a problem, since it would only be altered for the last line of the second file pass. Setting RS to "\x1c" only works in gawk en mawk by the way, but not in other awks so I changed it to `§` for the time being .

Answer (score 2):

Your records are still separated with RS so the 5 newlines are excluded from the count.

Use another delimiter for your FS and RS, and calculate the length of the whole $0 instead:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=RS="\x1c"}{c+=length($0)}END{print "total chars:"c}' abc
```

Output:

```
total chars:30
```

Note that using `""` or `"\x00"` would make it skip the last character.

By concept it's actually the same as:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=RS="\x1c"}END{print "total chars:" length($0)}' abc
```

Assuming that file doesn't contain any `\x1c`. It would still be invalid either way anyway if it has.

Comment: This would work for small files but could eventually lead to record too long errors. Various awks handle this in a different way..

Comment: @Scrutinizer It works the same in gawk, mawk and nawk. How would it act different? And of course everyone can read that but I'm not sure if there could be other simpler but still consistent solution for that.

Comment: @konsolebox as you noticed the other day in a dfferent thread, there is a max buffer size in nawk. Ditto for every awk but different values for each. You're telling awk to read the whole file as one field of one record so it WILL fail on every awk at some point for large files, it'll just be different points for every awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Please that is an obvious thing. I knew that even when I was I was just coding the code. But what solution could be better than that? Besides the example was not about large files and I was just proving a concept. Nothing serious should be extracted from that.

Comment: You asked `How would it act different?` so I answered it for you. Not sure why you asked if you already knew the answer. The better solution is to not read the whole file at one time, like Scrutinizer's solution, and if files that don't end in newlines are a concern, just add a test for that, e.g. in the END section.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah I was thinking about how awks would handle the syntax sorry.

Comment: no problem, I posted a solution now to show one way to address your concern about missing newlines.