# Multiple Field separator in awk script

Tags: linux, shell, awk

i have following code that gives me output as number of lines and words in a file. how can i use one more FS(file separator) that can be used to count total characters.??
(the output should be same as `wc file command` )

```
BEGIN {
  FS="\n| ";

}

{

  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
   w++
   l++
}

END { 
  print "Total no of Lines:"l;
  print "Total no of words:"w;

}
```

Comment: You're not using the field separator to count lines. The newline in `FS` doesn't have any effect. Only `w++` is in the `for` loop.

Comment: If you want to count characters, use `length($0)+1` (the 1 is for the newline, since it's not included in `$0`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in variable "$0" and function "length"

```
BEGIN {
  FS="\n| ";

}

{

  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
   w++
   l++
   c += length($0)+1
}

END { 
  print "Total no of Lines:"l;
  print "Total no of words:"w;
  print "Total no of chars:"c;

}
```

Edit: Add +1 to length to account for newline

Comment: Thanks but why it doesnt count line breaks. check answer with `wc file`

Answer (score 3):

Note, that with that field separator the script will count too many "words" since fields are considered words here and every space becomes a field separator.

Also, `awk` can only give a correct result for proper text files, where limits like maximum line lengths are observed and the last lines ends with a newline ..

The script could be simplified further a bit

```
{ 
  w+=NF
  c+=length+1
}

END { 
  print "Total no of lines:" NR
  print "Total no of words:" w
  print "Total no of chars:" c 
}
```